# Github Action: Next job was skipped even though the previous one was successful

Tags: github-actions

```
  generate_build_number:
    needs: [ aws, azure, gcp ]
    name: Generate Build Number
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ always() && contains(join(needs.*.result, ','), 'success') }}
    outputs:
      build_number: ${{ steps.buildnumber.outputs.build_number }}
    steps:
    - name: Generate build number
      id: buildnumber
      uses: einaregilsson/build-number@v3 
      with:
        token: ${{secrets.github_token}}

  zip_files:
    needs: generate_build_number
    name: Generate Zip File
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo ${{needs.generate_build_number.outputs.build_number}} > world.txt
      - uses: montudor/action-zip@v1
        with:
          args: zip -qq -r terraform-latest.zip aws azure gcp world.txt
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: terraform-latest
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/terraform-latest.zip
```

I want to run zip_files only after generate_build_number is completed successfully. How using the above code, even though generate_build_number finished, zip_files was skipped.

[image: For more details on the workflow]

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds), if the job_id in `needs` is completed successfully, the corresponding job will run. Are you sure `generate_build_number` completed successfully

Comment: generate_build_number completed successfully; I added a screenshot of the workflow

Comment: What happened to the `azure` job, since `generate_build_number` needs `azure`. If `azure` fails or is skipped. `zip_files` will be skipped too.

Comment: I only need either aws, azure, or gcp. I can't use a OR-statement in `needs` hence I added: `if: ${{ always() && contains(join(needs.*.result, ','), 'success') }}` .

So `zip_files` should be only dependent on `generate_build_number` (it ran) so im confused as to why `zip_files` was skipped

Comment: try a `if: ${{ always() && needs.generate_build_number.result=='success' }}` in `zip_files`. I'm guessing the issue has to do with `needs` not having an OR option, hence it considers all the job deps while resolving. So, in this case, since `azure` wasn't run, `zip_files` was skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when "needs" is set, Github actions will interpret the condition if: success(). So if there are any failures in steps, GH will treat the job as not successful.

Either you can add `continue-on-error: true` for each step in `generate_build_number` job

or

add a condition like below

```
 generate_build_number:
    needs: [ aws, azure, gcp ]
    name: Generate Build Number
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ always() && contains(join(needs.*.result, ','), 'success') }}
    outputs:
      build_number: ${{ steps.buildnumber.outputs.build_number }}
    steps:
    - name: Generate build number
      id: buildnumber
      uses: einaregilsson/build-number@v3 
      with:
        token: ${{secrets.github_token}}

  zip_files:
    needs: generate_build_number
    if: always()
    name: Generate Zip File
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo ${{needs.generate_build_number.outputs.build_number}} > world.txt
      - uses: montudor/action-zip@v1
        with:
          args: zip -qq -r terraform-latest.zip aws azure gcp world.txt
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: terraform-latest
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/terraform-latest.zip
```